# Creating a hive table from existing snapy files

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and Hive. I am working with `hadoop 2.7.0` and `hive 1.1.1`.

I have some files in snappy format. I have copied them in my hdfs. I want to know:
1. How to create a hive table using those files in hdfs.
2. how to configure hadoop to work with snappy files.

**EDIT**: I tried the following:

1.modified `core-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
           org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,
           org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
    </value>
</property>
```

2.Modified `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compress.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>


<property>
    <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
    <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/8417/repos/hadoop_ecosystem/hadoop-2.7.0/lib/native</value>
</property>
```

3. Installed snappy `brew install snappy`.
4. `cp /usr/local/Cellar/snappy/<version>/lib/snappy.* to $HADOOP_HOME/lib/snappy`
5. `cp /usr/local/Cellar/snappy/<version>/lib/snappy.* /Library/Java/Home/jre/lib`.

6.Added the following environment variables:

```
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

But I'm not able to make it work. I am getting the following error:

```
Machine:native user$ hadoop fs -text hive/part-00000.snappy 
15/09/24 19:25:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getDecompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getDecompressor(CodecPool.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec$Util.createInputStreamWithCodecPool(CompressionCodec.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.createInputStream(SnappyCodec.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Display$Text.getInputStream(Display.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Display$Cat.processPath(Display.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)


Machine:native user$ hadoop checknative
15/09/24 19:41:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false 
15/09/24 19:41:16 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have snappy installed and your hadoop is able to "see" it:

```
hadoop checknative
...
snappy:  true /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1
...
```

Also make sure your files' extensions are ".snappy". That's pretty much it.

Launch hive or beeline and create your table:

```
create external table t1(f1 int, ...) location '/path/to/dir/with/snappy/files';
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have edited my question. I tried doing what you suggested. Looked at several SO posts. Tried a lot of things but no luck!

Comment: Where did your hadoop distro come from? Did you install snappy? If you are lucky, you might get away with "yum install snappy", but probably what's causing the issue is that the native library that came with hadoop (if there was any) wasn't compiled for your system. You'll have to compile the native library and install it yourself. Check out this doc: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html